# Join to an oracle table valued function

Tags: oracle, inner-join, user-defined-functions

Is is possible to join to an Oracle table valued function?

```
SELECT 
   *
FROM 
  SOME_TABLE a
INNER JOIN 
  TABLE(GET_TABLE_LIST()) b ON = a.COL_A = b.COL_A
```

Comment: What are `GET_TRFRMENGMACHIENINFOT` and `se`?.

Comment: Sorry bad cut/paste..they are the types used in teh GET_TRFM... function.  Just showing about teh output would be from the table valued function.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can, yes.  Since I don't have your `get_TrfrmEngMachineInfoT` function, I'll create my own collection and join it to the `EMP` table in the `SCOTT` schema

```
SQL> create or replace type typ_person
  2      as object (
  3        person_id number,
  4        person_name varchar2(30)
  5      );
  6  /

Type created.

SQL> create or replace type tbl_person
  2    as table of typ_person;
  3  /

Type created.

SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  create or replace function get_person_list
  2    return tbl_person
  3  is
  4    l_people tbl_person;
  5  begin
  6    select typ_person( empno, ename )
  7      bulk collect into l_people
  8      from emp;
  9    return l_people;
 10* end;
SQL> /

Function created.

SQL> select p.*
  2    from emp e
  3         join table( get_person_list() ) p on (p.person_id = e.empno);

 PERSON_ID PERSON_NAME
---------- ------------------------------
      7623 PAV
      7369 smith
      7499 ALLEN
      7521 WARD
      7566 JONES
      7654 MARTIN
      7698 BLAKE
      7782 CLARK
      7788 SCOTT
      7839 KING
      7844 TURNER
      7876 ADAMS
      7900 SM0
      7902 FORD
      7934 MILLER
      1234 FOO

16 rows selected.
```

Comment: Justin you have solution for every problem +1, can't do more than that ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT a.*, b.*
from table_name a cross join table ( myFunc(a.id) ) b
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can work for you...

```
SELECT table_name.*, myFunc(table_name.OBJID) as new_field_name from table_name
```

That will select everything from the `table_name` table and add the result of the function in to the new set.

`myFunc` uses `table_name.OBJID` field to match some records and do whatever...